# Replicate the Lightning Experience Sidebar using the SLDS

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

Is there any documentation, a snippet, or anything that helps replicate the LEX Sidebar styling and functionality using the Lightning Design System? That includes dimensions, colors, collapse/expand functionality and toggle hover tooltips. Only some of these items are [documented here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/).

I spent maybe a couple of days trying to replicate the same look and feel as well as the behavior, and I think it's a bit of an overkill having to do such hacks.

The use case is showing a Visualforce page via popup from a lightning component. It'd be nice to keep it consistent and the sidebar functionality fits in perfectly as I have a bunch of different items that I'd like to display on the side for the user to be able to navigate between.

Comment: Did you check add this chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-lightning-insp/pcpmcffcomlcjgpcheokdfcjipanjdpc?hl=en